# Failed to build the sal-distributed-datastore, Error while generating Javadoc in OpenDaylight Controller

Tags: eclipse, maven, opendaylight

I'm tring to execute an mvn clean install with the OpenDaylight Controller Project in Eclipse Oxygen (Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)), i've tryed to build the code with the simple steps: I've imported the git code, from the url `https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/p/<project_repo_name>.git`, and runned with the goals: clean install -Pq (because i'm always get errors when the tests are executed if the controller are builded for the first time) and during the build i'm get this error when the build reach the odl-config-api part:

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.karaf.tooling:karaf-maven-plugin:4.0.10:features-generate-descriptor (default-features-generate-descriptor) on project odl-config-api: Execution default-features-generate-descriptor of goal org.apache.karaf.tooling:karaf-maven-plugin:4.0.10:features-generate-descriptor failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.karaf.tooling:karaf-maven-plugin:4.0.10:features-generate-descriptor: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    extension>org.apache.karaf.tooling:karaf-maven-plugin:4.0.10
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/apache/karaf/tooling/karaf-maven-plugin/4.0.10/karaf-maven-plugin-4.0.10.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/2.1.1/sisu-inject-bean-2.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.9.4/sisu-guice-2.9.4-no_aop.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.11/aether-util-1.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/0.9.0.M2/aether-util-0.9.0.M2.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.3/maven-plugin-annotations-3.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-http/2.10/wagon-http-2.10.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-http-shared/2.10/wagon-http-shared-2.10.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/jsoup/jsoup/1.7.2/jsoup-1.7.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.5/httpclient-4.3.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3.2/httpcore-4.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/apache/karaf/org.apache.karaf.util/4.0.10/org.apache.karaf.util-4.0.10.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/apache/felix/org.apache.felix.utils/1.10.0/org.apache.felix.utils-1.10.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/apache/karaf/jaas/org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot/4.0.10/org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot-4.0.10.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/apache/karaf/tooling/org.apache.karaf.tools.utils/4.0.10/org.apache.karaf.tools.utils-4.0.10.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-jdk14/1.7.12/slf4j-jdk14-1.7.12.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-filtering/1.0-beta-4/maven-filtering-1.0-beta-4.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-build-api/0.0.4/plexus-build-api-0.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0/plexus-utils-3.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/apache/felix/maven-bundle-plugin/3.3.0/maven-bundle-plugin-3.3.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/biz/aQute/bnd/biz.aQute.bndlib/3.3.0/biz.aQute.bndlib-3.3.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.6/maven-archiver-2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/0.7/maven-shared-utils-0.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/jsr305-2.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2.8.1/plexus-archiver-2.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.3.2/plexus-io-2.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[35] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-tree/2.1/maven-dependency-tree-2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[36] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0/doxia-sink-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[37] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-site-renderer/1.0/doxia-site-renderer-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[38] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.0/doxia-core-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[39] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-i18n/1.0-beta-7/plexus-i18n-1.0-beta-7.jar
[ERROR] urls[40] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/1.1.7/plexus-velocity-1.1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[41] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.5/velocity-1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[42] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[43] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-decoration-model/1.0/doxia-decoration-model-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[44] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2/commons-collections-3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[45] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-apt/1.0/doxia-module-apt-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[46] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-fml/1.0/doxia-module-fml-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[47] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xdoc/1.0/doxia-module-xdoc-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[48] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xhtml/1.0/doxia-module-xhtml-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[49] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/jdom/jdom/1.1/jdom-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[50] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/apache/felix/org.apache.felix.fileinstall/3.6.0/org.apache.felix.fileinstall-3.6.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[51] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/apache/karaf/features/org.apache.karaf.features.core/4.0.10/org.apache.karaf.features.core-4.0.10.jar
[ERROR] urls[52] = file:/C:/Users/kevin/.m2/repository/org/apache/karaf/profile/org.apache.karaf.profile.core/4.0.10/org.apache.karaf.profile.core-4.0.10.jar.....
...I've removed part of the log error, since it's exceeded the body limit.
```

My network is working normally and i'm runnig the eclipse in Windows 10 system (i don't know if it's really matter), i've don't edited any of the pom.xml.
I'm doing something wrong, or forgetting any step? Any tips?

---

UPDATE

I've got this new error aparentilly it's rellated to wrong writed code, but i know that's the code is correct.

ERROR:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.4:jar (attach-javadocs) on project sal-distributed-datastore: MavenReportException: Error while generating Javadoc:
[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\ShardWriteTransaction.java:26: error: unknown tag: author:
[ERROR] * @author: syedbahm
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\ShardReadWriteTransaction.java:19: error: unknown tag: author:
[ERROR] * @author: syedbahm
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\ShardReadTransaction.java:20: error: unknown tag: author:
[ERROR] * @author: syedbahm
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\jmx\mbeans\shard\ShardStatsMXBean.java:17: error: unknown tag: author:
[ERROR] * @author: syedbahm
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\databroker\AbstractDOMBrokerTransaction.java:34: warning: no @param for storeTxFactories
[ERROR] protected AbstractDOMBrokerTransaction(final Object identifier,
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\databroker\AbstractDOMBrokerTransaction.java:70: warning: no @return
[ERROR] protected Collection<T> getSubtransactions() {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\databroker\DOMBrokerReadOnlyTransaction.java:30: warning: no @param for storeTxFactories
[ERROR] protected DOMBrokerReadOnlyTransaction(Object identifier,
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\databroker\DOMBrokerReadWriteTransaction.java:31: warning: no @param for commitImpl
[ERROR] protected DOMBrokerReadWriteTransaction(Object identifier,
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\databroker\DOMBrokerWriteOnlyTransaction.java:24: warning: no @param for commitImpl
[ERROR] public DOMBrokerWriteOnlyTransaction(Object identifier,
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\DatastoreContext.java:558: warning: no @param for id
[ERROR] public Builder shardManagerPersistenceId(final String id) {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\DatastoreContext.java:558: warning: no @return
[ERROR] public Builder shardManagerPersistenceId(final String id) {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\DistributedDataStoreFactory.java:32: warning: no @param for schemaService
[ERROR] public static AbstractDataStore createInstance(final SchemaService schemaService,
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\DistributedDataStoreFactory.java:32: warning: no @param for initialDatastoreContext
[ERROR] public static AbstractDataStore createInstance(final SchemaService schemaService,
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\DistributedDataStoreFactory.java:32: warning: no @param for datastoreSnapshotRestore
[ERROR] public static AbstractDataStore createInstance(final SchemaService schemaService,
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\DistributedDataStoreFactory.java:32: warning: no @param for actorSystemProvider
[ERROR] public static AbstractDataStore createInstance(final SchemaService schemaService,
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\DistributedDataStoreFactory.java:32: warning: no @param for bundleContext
[ERROR] public static AbstractDataStore createInstance(final SchemaService schemaService,
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\DistributedDataStoreFactory.java:32: warning: no @return
[ERROR] public static AbstractDataStore createInstance(final SchemaService schemaService,
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\config\Configuration.java:25: warning: no @param for memberName
[ERROR] @Nonnull Collection<String> getMemberShardNames(@Nonnull MemberName memberName);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\config\Configuration.java:25: warning: no @return
[ERROR] @Nonnull Collection<String> getMemberShardNames(@Nonnull MemberName memberName);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\config\Configuration.java:30: warning: no @param for nameSpace
[ERROR] @Nullable String getModuleNameFromNameSpace(@Nonnull String nameSpace);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\config\Configuration.java:30: warning: no @return
[ERROR] @Nullable String getModuleNameFromNameSpace(@Nonnull String nameSpace);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\config\Configuration.java:35: warning: no @param for moduleName
[ERROR] @Nullable String getShardNameForModule(@Nonnull String moduleName);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\config\Configuration.java:35: warning: no @return
[ERROR] @Nullable String getShardNameForModule(@Nonnull String moduleName);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\config\Configuration.java:40: warning: no @param for prefix
[ERROR] @Nullable String getShardNameForPrefix(@Nonnull DOMDataTreeIdentifier prefix);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\config\Configuration.java:40: warning: no @return
[ERROR] @Nullable String getShardNameForPrefix(@Nonnull DOMDataTreeIdentifier prefix);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\config\Configuration.java:45: warning: no @param for shardName
[ERROR] @Nonnull Collection<MemberName> getMembersFromShardName(@Nonnull String shardName);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\config\Configuration.java:45: warning: no @return
[ERROR] @Nonnull Collection<MemberName> getMembersFromShardName(@Nonnull String shardName);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\config\Configuration.java:50: warning: no @param for moduleName
[ERROR] @Nullable ShardStrategy getStrategyForModule(@Nonnull String moduleName);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\config\Configuration.java:50: warning: no @return
[ERROR] @Nullable ShardStrategy getStrategyForModule(@Nonnull String moduleName);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\config\Configuration.java:55: warning: no @return
[ERROR] Set<String> getAllShardNames();
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\config\Configuration.java:60: warning: no @param for config
[ERROR] void addModuleShardConfiguration(@Nonnull ModuleShardConfiguration config);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\config\Configuration.java:65: warning: no @param for config
[ERROR] void addPrefixShardConfiguration(@Nonnull PrefixShardConfiguration config);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\config\Configuration.java:70: warning: no @param for prefix
[ERROR] void removePrefixShardConfiguration(@Nonnull DOMDataTreeIdentifier prefix);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\config\Configuration.java:82: warning: no @return
[ERROR] Collection<MemberName> getUniqueMemberNamesForAllShards();
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\config\Configuration.java:92: warning: no @param for shardName
[ERROR] void addMemberReplicaForShard(String shardName, MemberName memberName);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\config\Configuration.java:92: warning: no @param for memberName
[ERROR] void addMemberReplicaForShard(String shardName, MemberName memberName);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\config\Configuration.java:97: warning: no @param for shardName
[ERROR] void removeMemberReplicaForShard(String shardName, MemberName memberName);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\config\Configuration.java:97: warning: no @param for memberName
[ERROR] void removeMemberReplicaForShard(String shardName, MemberName memberName);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\config\Configuration.java:102: warning: no @param for prefix
[ERROR] @Nullable ShardStrategy getStrategyForPrefix(@Nonnull DOMDataTreeIdentifier prefix);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\config\Configuration.java:102: warning: no @return
[ERROR] @Nullable ShardStrategy getStrategyForPrefix(@Nonnull DOMDataTreeIdentifier prefix);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\config\ModuleShardConfigProvider.java:22: warning: no @param for configuration
[ERROR] @Nonnull Map<String, ModuleConfig.Builder> retrieveModuleConfigs(@Nonnull Configuration configuration);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\config\ModuleShardConfigProvider.java:22: warning: no @return
[ERROR] @Nonnull Map<String, ModuleConfig.Builder> retrieveModuleConfigs(@Nonnull Configuration configuration);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\messages\PrimaryShardInfo.java:42: warning: no @return
[ERROR] public @Nonnull ActorSelection getPrimaryShardActor() {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\messages\PrimaryShardInfo.java:49: warning: no @return
[ERROR] public short getPrimaryShardVersion() {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\messages\PrimaryShardInfo.java:57: warning: no @return
[ERROR] public @Nonnull Optional<DataTree> getLocalShardDataTree() {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\messages\RemovePrefixShardReplica.java:30: warning: no @param for memberName
[ERROR] public RemovePrefixShardReplica(@Nonnull final YangInstanceIdentifier prefix,
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\messages\RemoveShardReplica.java:29: warning: no @param for memberName
[ERROR] public RemoveShardReplica(@Nonnull String shardName, @Nonnull MemberName memberName) {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\shardmanager\ShardManagerSnapshot.java:42: warning: no @param for shardList
[ERROR] public static ShardManagerSnapshot forShardList(final @Nonnull List<String> shardList) {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\shardmanager\ShardManagerSnapshot.java:42: warning: no @return
[ERROR] public static ShardManagerSnapshot forShardList(final @Nonnull List<String> shardList) {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\utils\ActorContext.java:280: warning: no @return
[ERROR] public Future<ActorRef> findLocalShardAsync(final String shardName) {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\utils\ActorContext.java:416: warning: no @param for messageSupplier
[ERROR] public void broadcast(final Function<Short, Object> messageSupplier, Class<?> messageClass) {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\utils\ActorContext.java:416: warning: no @param for messageClass
[ERROR] public void broadcast(final Function<Short, Object> messageSupplier, Class<?> messageClass) {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\utils\NormalizedNodeAggregator.java:42: warning: no @param for rootIdentifier
[ERROR] public static Optional<NormalizedNode<?,?>> aggregate(final YangInstanceIdentifier rootIdentifier,
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\utils\NormalizedNodeAggregator.java:42: warning: no @param for nodes
[ERROR] public static Optional<NormalizedNode<?,?>> aggregate(final YangInstanceIdentifier rootIdentifier,
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\utils\NormalizedNodeAggregator.java:42: warning: no @param for schemaContext
[ERROR] public static Optional<NormalizedNode<?,?>> aggregate(final YangInstanceIdentifier rootIdentifier,
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\utils\NormalizedNodeAggregator.java:42: warning: no @param for logicalDatastoreType
[ERROR] public static Optional<NormalizedNode<?,?>> aggregate(final YangInstanceIdentifier rootIdentifier,
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\utils\NormalizedNodeAggregator.java:42: warning: no @return
[ERROR] public static Optional<NormalizedNode<?,?>> aggregate(final YangInstanceIdentifier rootIdentifier,
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\datastore\utils\NormalizedNodeAggregator.java:42: warning: no @throws for org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang.data.api.schema.tree.DataValidationFailedException
[ERROR] public static Optional<NormalizedNode<?,?>> aggregate(final YangInstanceIdentifier rootIdentifier,
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\src\main\java\org\opendaylight\controller\cluster\sharding\DistributedShardFactory.java:52: warning: no @return
[ERROR] CompletionStage<Void> close();
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\target\generated-sources\config-binding\org\opendaylight\controller\config\yang\config\concurrent_data_broker\DomConcurrentDataBrokerModuleMXBean.java:25: warning: no @param for maxDataBrokerCommitQueueSize
[ERROR] void setMaxDataBrokerCommitQueueSize(java.lang.Integer maxDataBrokerCommitQueueSize);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\target\generated-sources\config-binding\org\opendaylight\controller\config\yang\config\concurrent_data_broker\DomConcurrentDataBrokerModuleMXBean.java:32: warning: no @param for maxDataBrokerFutureCallbackQueueSize
[ERROR] void setMaxDataBrokerFutureCallbackQueueSize(java.lang.Integer maxDataBrokerFutureCallbackQueueSize);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\target\generated-sources\config-binding\org\opendaylight\controller\config\yang\config\concurrent_data_broker\DomConcurrentDataBrokerModuleMXBean.java:39: warning: no @param for maxDataBrokerFutureCallbackPoolSize
[ERROR] void setMaxDataBrokerFutureCallbackPoolSize(java.lang.Integer maxDataBrokerFutureCallbackPoolSize);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Command line was: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin\javadoc.exe" @options @packages
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Refer to the generated Javadoc files in 'C:\Users\kevin\git\controller\opendaylight\md-sal\sal-distributed-datastore\target\apidocs' dir.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :sal-distributed-datastore
```

There's two errors, i've edited the question, because i've thinked that the initial error had been resolved with the `-Pq,ide clean generate-sources` but after execute this command i've got the second error.

Any ideia of what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem re. `maven-javadoc-plugin` seems to be due to `"error: unknown tag: author:"` - that's fixed by https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/#/c/66268/.  *(FYI the JavaDoc output can be a bit confusing; it's only the lines where there is an "error: " at the end that cause the build to fail; all lines starting with [ERROR] but ending in "warning: " do not.)*

The **REAL** question is why you hit this locally when this works for everyone else and on the ODL Jenkins build...  The reason for that is if we note your `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\`... you appear to be building ODL on Java 9 - and that is not supported, yet! I've just proposed https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/#/c/66269/ to avoid similar problems for others in the future (until we're ready).  Until then, please both build and run ODL only with Java 8 and you will have a lot less problems.

PS: I was not crystal clear if you've fully resolved your first problem re. `karaf-maven-plugin`, and are now only asking about your second problem re. `maven-javadoc-plugin` - it's best to remove from your question what you have resolved, or open separate new questions for new things you run into. But the `karaf-maven-plugin` could very well have issues when running the build under Java 9 as well.

Comment: thanks again for the quick reply, i reimported the controller project to restart the installation, now using the java 8 (Java SE Development Kit 8u152) i used the clean install (whitout skip tests parameter) and got an error that says: `Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.8.0 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_152/../lib/tools.jar`, you have any idea of what's causing this?

Comment: just to stay clear the complete error was:
`Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check (check-license) on project config-api: Execution check-license of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.8.0 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_152/../lib/tools.jar -> [Help 1]`

Comment: I see that it's a jre problem, i'm using JRE instead the JDK, i've changed and the problem has fixed